# float, tuple and frozenset are all hashable, why frozenset is special

Tags: python, hash, frozenset

In Python3.7.4

When I test to run this:

```py
>>> hash((1.000001))
2305843009025
>>> hash(1.000001)
2305843009025
>>> (1.000001) == 1.000001
True
>>> [1.000001] == 1.000001
False
```

But why:

```py
>>> frozenset({1.000001}) == 1.000001
False
>>> hash(frozenset({1.000001}))
8757482414179413028
```

float, tuple and frozenset are all hashable, why frozenset is special

Comment: There are no tuples here, and what is your question? `frozenset` is hashable. If it wasn't, you'd get an error.

Comment: The first is not a tuple but a float.

Comment: `(1.000001)` is not a tuple - `(1.000001,)` is - note the comma.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is your question? In what way do you believe frozenset is special, compared to the other types you have referenced?

Comment: thank you all, now,I know I made a stupid mistake, I will pull an explanation later

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake. The comma is the identity of the tuple.

```py
>>> hash(frozenset({1.000001}))
8757482414179413028
>>> hash((1.000001,))
2305846529543933606
>>> hash((1.000001))
2305843009025
>>> hash(1.000001)
2305843009025
>>> type((1.000001))
<class 'float'>
>>> type(1.000001)
<class 'float'>
```